# Flask display data while function loads

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Hi I want to do something like this in flask

```
@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def getData():
    url = "";
    data = requests.request("GET", url);
    a big array = json.loads(data.text);
    for item in the big array:
        data = requests.request("GET", item);
        data = json.loads(data.text);
        display the data ("displayTable.html", name=item, date=data[0][0]["date"], price=data[0][0]["school"]);
```

displayTable extends layout.html and appends the data to the block

I am able to display all the data at once by storing it in an array and returning render template with data=array after I grab all the data from the urls

but I'm wondering if I can display one right after it loads, so you can see them being displayed one by one?